# OCTAVE Solving Ordinary differential equation

Tags: octave, numerical-methods, ode, differential-equations

I have to solve the following differential equation with Octave

[image]
[image]

Where

- `A` is a matrix of `(N-1)X(N-1)` ,
- `f` is defined as: `f(x,t)=1000*sqrt(|1-t|)` ,
- `μ=1`,
- `u(x,0)=1000x(1-x)(1+(3/2)x^3)`,
- the bar has lenght `L=1` and `u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0` for all `t` ,
- `h` is `1/N` (`N` number of partitions of the interval).

I have read how to use the command, but I do not understand how to use it in this specific case. How can I input the function du/dt. I'd be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, and there's some information you've left out (e.g. the specific nature of x).

However, as an example of how to 'run' the lsode function, here's an example below, which makes the following assumption:

- You mentioned a 'bar' of length 1, and N partitions/bins, so I'm assuming X is a vector representing the corresponding positions at the 'edges' of the bins, in which case you have N+1 edges. Since you are given the solutions for the 'outer' edges (i.e. x = 0 and x = 1), we only care for the 'inner edges', hence we only need to deal with vectors of N-1 elements (hence the size of matrix A).

```matlab
  N         = 4;   % number of bins
  mu        = 1;
  h         = 1 / N;
  A_matrix  = rand( N - 1, N - 1 );
  t_rvector = [0 : 20].';

  x_cvector = linspace( 0, 1, N + 1 ).';   % N+1 edges, including outer ones
  x_cvector = x_cvector(2 : end - 1);      % discard outer edges, keep inner only.


% Create f(t) as defined in the question, but vectorised w.r.t. x
% (i.e. outputting an N-1 element vector that can be added to a corresponding u vector)

  f_function = @(t) 1000 .* sqrt( abs( 1 - t ) ) .* ones( size( x_cvector ) );


% Create a u0 vector (of N-1 elements, corresponding to inner edges on the bar)
  u0_cvector = 1000 .* x_cvector .* (1 - x_cvector) .* (1 + (3 / 2) .* x_cvector .^ 3);

% Create a 'wrapper' function of the form expected by `lsode`
  ode_function = @(u_cvector, t) -mu ./ (h .^ 2) .* A_matrix * u_cvector + f_function(t);

% Run `lsode`
  [u_matrix, ISTATE, MSG] = lsode( ode_function, u0_cvector, t_rvector )

% Pad u_matrix with 0s on left and right, corresponding to x=0 and x=1 values
  TimePoints = length( t_rvector );
  ZeroColumn = zeros( TimePoints, 1 );
  u_matrix   = [ ZeroColumn, u_matrix, ZeroColumn ];

% Plot the curves (when plotting a matrix, each column is treated as a separate plot), therefore if you want to plot along the 'components' of u (corresponding to positions in $
  plot ( u_matrix.' );
```

This may not be the same as your problem, but the above code runs as expected, so hopefully it will help you as a starting point.

One thing to note, the `u` vector passed into the `lsode` function needs to be in 'column' form. (the list of timepoints can be column or row, doesn't matter).

Comment: Alternatively, it may be that you need to account for the outer edges explicitly in your input/output vectors. I have no idea, that's up to you to figure out. Also, you may have to call `lsode_options` to modify the kind of ode you want to run, or initial conditions, stepsize, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help you´ve been very helpful. I have only one question, I'm not understanding what is the t_rvector for. I noticed that it increases or decreases the number of rows of the solution, but what does it change that?

Comment: @usuario2599 glad it helped. To be honest, I also only know what I read by typing `help lsode` in the console. Regarding the vector of time values, the documentation there says: "The third argument is a vector, T, specifying the time values for which a solution is sought.". So it sounds like instead of having to provide all the timepoints, the underlying fortran algorithm decides the range and stepsizes adaptively, and all you need to do is provide timepoints of interest to you where you want `u` to be evaluated. Like I said, though, I'm not an expert.

Comment: Ahh ok, now I understand what´s the t_rvector for. Thanks !. Now i'm plotting the solution for different parts of the time interval but I don't know how to imput the bounder values :u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0 for all t. Only in the case of u_0 it's working. Here it's the plot https://imgur.com/a/q9FvkoR

Comment: In the example I gave above, I explicitly removed x=0 and x=1 from the linspace I created (see line 7 where I say 'discard outer edges'). The reason is because I know that for all t, when x=0 or x=1, then u=0 (based on your problem formulation). Therefore when the time comes for plotting, you can simply get your u matrix consisting of N-1 elements columns, and pad it with 0 on the left and right. I updated the example above to show this.